# Code-comment short-cut not working on MacOS

Tags: goland

Still new to Goland

Note:

- I am using a Danish keyboard on MacOs Big Sur.
- GoLand 2020.3 Build: GO-2003.7148.71 build on January 26 2021.

I have problems commenting out code in Goland (command+shift+7)

It opens the help menu, but I was expecting to comment out code?

Comment: Does it work if you reassign the shortcut to the same in the settings: `File | Settings | Keymap`?

Comment: It does not look like I can reassign, I can add, remove?

Comment: You can remove the current shortcut, then click on the same row and choose Add  Keyboard Shortcut, and press Command+Shift+7.

Comment: Right, I tried that - but then it changes focus away from the editor. Hmm

Comment: Do you use any national keyboard, e.g., German/Danish?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am on a danish keyboard

Comment: Do you use Ubuntu or another Linux distro?

Comment: Right, I am on MacOs Big Sur

Comment: What version of GoLand are you using? 2020.3.1 or higher/lower?

Comment: Sorry, I am slow :-) Thanks, I am on 2020.3 Build: GO-2003.7148.71 build on January 26 2021.

Comment: It's strange that your default Comment with Line/Block comment shortcut is `Command+Shift+7`. My default shortcuts `Command+/` & `Option+Command+/`. Could you please try to change Keymap to default one (macOS) in the settings: `Preferences | Keymap | Dropdown | macOS`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that - my keyboard "/" key is shared with "7"

Comment: Please, try out the EAP release, you can download it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/

The issue should be fixed there.

Comment: Thanks, tried it out - still the same.

Comment: So, please, disable the default macOS shortcut: `System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcuts | App Shortcut | Show Help menu`. After that, navigate to the IDE settings: `Preferences | Keymap | Main menu | Code | Folding | Comment with Line Comment`, and add a new shortcut to Command+Shift+7, then apply changes.